# This Keyword *within* Javascript Module

Tags: javascript, this, modular

I'm creating a Javascript module which task is basically to dynamically generate an open modal via Ajax on the click of a button. This button has a data-attribute that I pass to the Ajax call to tell it which modal I want to open.

Here's a simplified version of the module:

```
( function() { 

let modalwindow = {

    init: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    }, 

    bindEvents: function() {
        $( document ).on( 'click', '[data-action="open-modal"]', this.ajaxCall.bind( this ) );
    },

    ajaxCall: function() {

        $.ajax({

            url: ajax.url,
            type: 'post',
            context: this,
            data: {
                modal_id: this.modalID, // In this case, I need *this* to refer to the button
                action: 'open_modal'
            }, 
            success: function ( response ) {

               // In this case, I need *this* to refer to the modalwindow object

               this.openModal( response, this.modalID );

            }

        });

    },

    openModal: function( response, modalID ) {

         $( response ).appendTo( Body ).attr( 'data-state', 'active-modal' );

    }

}

modalwindow.init();

})()
```

The problem is, in the `ajaxCall` method I need the **this** keyword to refer to two different things: I need it to refer to the button when I set the modal_id parameter; and I need it to refer to the modalwindow object to call the `openModal` method on success. How do I do that?

Right now **this** always refers to the modalwindow object, in fact `openModal` works; but the modal_id parameter is wrong because in there **this** should refer to the button.

I'm very new to Modular JS and this has been driving me crazy. I've found similar questions but none seem to address the issue for methods all within the module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: *"This Keyword *within* Javascript Module"* The word "module" now has [a specific technical meaning](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-modules) in JavaScript (whereas before ES2015, it didn't, and was used loosely to refer to any number of different ways of solving the problem). So I'd stay away from it when not referring to an actual JavaScript module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already binding `this` when setting up the handler, so `this` in `ajaxCall` will refer to the modal window. So accept the event argument in `ajaxCall`:

```
ajaxCall: function(e) {
```

...and then where you need the button, use `e.currentTarget`, and where you need the modal window, use `this`. In an event handler, `e.currentTarget` (and `this`) both refer to the element the handler was hooked up to (as opposed to `e.target`, which refers to the element where the event was targeted, which may be a descendant of `e.currentTarget`).